# remove “Choose an Option” and make another value the default option

Tags: magento

I would like to remove “Choose an Option” and make another value the default option.

I have googled it quite a bit but I haven’t found a solution other than paid extensions (which I would prefer not to purchase at this point because I am still learning Magento and seeing if it is viable for our small business).

As far as I can tell, I need to modify the javascript in js/varien/product.js.

Also, I might need to make changes to template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Can anyone shed some light on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Choose an Option" from configurable dropdown in Magento:

https://gist.github.com/iamgraeme/5547777

Comment: can you tell the name of the file ..where  i can edit it

Comment: As i mentioned earlier googled code did not worked i have edited but still it did not worked